# How to use keras model inside other model in TPU

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, tpu

I am trying to convert a keras model to tpu model in google colab, but this model has another model inside.

Take a look at the code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EmIrheKnrNYNNHPp0J7EBjw2WjsPXFVJ

This is a modified version of one of the examples in the google tpu documentation:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/fashion_mnist.ipynb

If the sub_model is converted and used directly it works, but if the sub model is inside another model it does not work. I need the sub model type of network because i am trying to train a GAN network that has 2 networks inside (gan=generator+discriminator) so if this test works probably it will work with the gan too.

I have tried several things:

- Convert to tpu the model without converting the sub model, in that case when training starts an error is prompted related to the inputs of the sub model.
- Convert both the model and sub model to tpu, in that case an error is prompted when converting the "parent" model, the exception only says at the end "layers".
- Convert only the sub model to tpu, in that case no error is prompted but the training is not accelerated by the tpu and it is extremely slow like if no conversion to tpu was made at all.
- Using fixed batch size or not, both have the same result, the model does not work.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Set everyone can see permission at google drive for : https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/fashion_mnist.ipynb 

To get better help

Answer (score 0):

Divide into parts only use submodel at tpu first. Then put something simple instead of submodel and use the model in TPU. If this does not work , create something very simple which includes similar structure with models you are sure that are working and then step by step add things to converge your complex model which you want to use in TPU.

I am struggling with such things. What I did at the very beginning using MNIST is trained the model and get the coefficients outside rewrite relu dense dropout and NN matricies myself and run the model using numpy and then cupy and then pyopencl and then I replaced functions with my own raw cuda C and opencl functions so that getting deeper and simpler I can find what is wrong when something does not work. At last I write my genetic selective training algo and learned a lot.

And most important it gave me the opportunity to try some crazy ideas for training and modelling and manuplating and making sense of NN coffecients.

The problem in my opinion is TF - Keras etc are too high level. Optimizers - Solvers , there is too much unknown. Even neural networks are not under control. GAN is problematic while training it does not converge everytime takes days to train most of the time. Even if you train. You dont know any idea how it converges. Most of the tricks - techniques which protects you from vanishing gradient are not mathematically backed they are nevertheless works very amazingly. (?!?)

**Go simpler deeper and and complexity step by step. Follow a practicing on which you comprehend as much as you can ** It will cost some time and energy but you will benefit it tremendously in my opinion.